# Open PayPal app from iOS app and start payment transaction

Tags: ios, paypal

In a native iOS app, is it possible to open the PayPal app from my own app and pass data to start a payment transaction? If yes, how?

Comment: Have you looked at PayPal mobile SDK? Here's a link: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/mobile/mobile-sdk-overview/

Comment: Noam, I suppose the SDK must be used inside your app to perform payment inside your app, while I was looking for a different solution (passing data to the PayPal app from my own app)

Answer (score 0):

The comments above are accurate - you should integrate the [PayPal mobile SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK) into your app to take PayPal wallet or credit card payments.